# PHP Session - Form Submit Logs Out User

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a member form that requires a password to gain access to it.

Once the user has entered the password they may then enter in their details in the form.

However the problem is that when the user submits the form they are getting logged out of the session.

I would like the user to remain logged in when they hit submit and then be directed to a second member form further down the same page.

Here is the code I am using for the password login:

`

```
<?php
//encrypted password here - example is 'hello'
$password = 'aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d';

session_start();
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    } else {
        header ("Location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>


<html>
<head><title>Login Page</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="registration/signup.php">
      Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Here is the code I am using at the top of the password protected page (Member Form Page):

```
<?php
require('../access.php');
?>
```

And this is the form on the password protected page (Member Form Page):

```
<form action="#sky-form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">

            <fieldset>                  
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                        <label class="input">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-left">Enter you full name</b>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                        <label class="input">
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                            <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-left">Enter a valid email address</b>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </fieldset>

            <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                <button type="submit" button class="border-button">NEXT</button>

            </div>  
            </div>
            </form>
```

I know that the password method above is not the most secure, however I really dont require it to be. I just want the member form to be available to everyone who has been given a password for it.

Huge thank you to anyone who can help me out with this.

Comment: You’re killing your session with `session_destroy`, so don’t expect it to works afterwards …

Comment: and before that you are freeing all session variables that are currently registered..http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: ok thanks CBroe if I remove session_destroy it works. However this now means I need to log the user out of the session if the user hits one of the non-password protected links, Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: What I mean is that if you exit the protected page and then try to login again the login page is just blank. Is this because the user is still logged in?

Comment: yes.. the user is still logged in. That's why the login page is just blank.

Comment: ok thanks choxx. How would I go about clearing the session if the user leaves the protected member page?

Comment: or.. if clearing the session cant be done without closing the browser is there a way I could have the user bypass the login page and go straight to the member page instead?

Comment: ok I think I have managed it.. albeit in maybe a rather messy way. I added this to the bottom of the login page: 
    <?php
    exit();
    endif;
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
    ?>

Comment: Is this ok, or should I use another method?